# how to custom filter search in datatable laravel,

Tags: ajax, laravel

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    tabel_sales = $('#tabel_sales').DataTable({
        'bLengthChange': false,
        scrollXInner: true,
        dom : 'frtp',
        processing : true,
        serverside : true,
        ajax : {
            'url' : '{{ url("data/data_sales") }}',
            'data' : function(data){
                month = $('#month').val();
                console.log(data);
                data.searchByMonth = month;
            }
        }
    })
    $('#month').change(function(e){
        tabel_sales.draw();
    })
})
```

controller

```
$testing = $request->get('searchByMonth');
$get_po_apar = DB::table('tabel_header_po')
                    ->where([
                        ['kode_mitra', Auth::user()->kode_mitra],
                        ['no_po', 'LIKE', '%TRX%'],
                        ['created_by', $gd->kode_user]
                    ])
                    ->whereMonth('created_at',$testing)
                    ->get();
        if (count($get_po_apar) > 0) {
            $po = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> ' . count($get_po_apar) . ' Po Apar</button>';
            $fetch[] = $po;
        } else {
            $po = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 0 Po Apar</button>';
            $fetch[] = $po;
        }
```

i have problem, I want to display data based on the month dropdown I chose, automatically the data that appears will change based on the dropdown

```
please Help me!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
tabel_sales.columns("index column" or "column name").search("value").draw();
```

This link: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

May I help you!

Comment: I use datatable, not Yajra, and I want to retrieve data from the select option I chose,
how to get value from select option and throw to controller via datatable

Comment: when you change dropdown, you get value of dropdown by js or jquery, after you search by column month and value search is value from dropdown. You should read document of datatable from my link. It may be help you. Thanks